# check if a list already contains an object with similar values - java

Tags: java, arraylist, collections

I need to add an object to a list only when the given list does not already contain a object with similar properties

```
List<Identifier> listObject; //list
Identifier i = new Identifier(); //New object to be added
i.type = "TypeA";
i.id = "A";
if(!listObject.contains(i)) {   // check
    listObject.add(i);  
}
```

I tried `contains()` to have a check on the existing list. If the list already has an object say `j` with `j.type = "TypeA"` and `j.id = "A"`, I don't want to add that to list.

Can you please help me achieve this by overriding equals or any solution that can do?

Comment: Unfortunately I can't use a set,  those classes are already written in the existing system. Would be nice If I can put in a condition with existing criteria.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Implement `equals()` and `hashCode()` in your `Identifier` class.

If you don't want to perform a check before adding the element, you can change your `listObject` from `List` to `Set`. A `Set` is a collection that contains no duplicate elements.

Follows an example of implementation automatically created by Eclipse IDE:

```
@Override
public int hashCode() {
    final int prime = 31;
    int result = 1;
    result = prime * result + ((id == null) ? 0 : id.hashCode());
    result = prime * result + ((type == null) ? 0 : type.hashCode());
    return result;
}

@Override
public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    if (this == obj)
        return true;
    if (obj == null)
        return false;
    if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
        return false;
    Identifier other = (Identifier) obj;
    if (id == null) {
        if (other.id != null)
            return false;
    } else if (!id.equals(other.id))
        return false;
    if (type == null) {
        if (other.type != null)
            return false;
    } else if (!type.equals(other.type))
        return false;
    return true;
}
```

Comment: And use your IDE to generate `equals` and `hashCode`, no need to write it +1

Comment: Won't that cause some bugs here seeing as `Identifier` is mutable object?

Comment: Yes, uou can use List and perform a check before adding the element.

Comment: @hbelmiro, that's a dirty way to implement `equals`, what would you do if we had more than 2 fields?

Comment: @AndrewTobilko I would just add the other fields. What do you suggest?

Comment: @hbelmiro, `if (this == o) return true;
        Identifier i;
        return o instanceof Identifier && Objects.equals(id, (i = (Identifier)o).id) && Objects.equals(type, i.type);`

Comment: @AndrewTobilko And what would you do if we had more than 2 fields? Your suggestion is as dirty as mine. The only difference is that you're using just one if statement.

Comment: @hbelmiro, `instanceof` and `Objects.equals` look more readable than a plenty of  your `if` statements. My solution occupies only 3 lines and +1 for each new field.

Comment: @AndrewTobilko For me both ways are readable and good implementations. I would use yours if we had few attributes to test. But if we had a lot of them, I'd use mine, because I don't like if statements with many &&s or ||s. I think it's personal. And just to remember, my example was created automatically by Eclipse IDE.